# Loop with rolling total in c

Tags: c, loops, cumulative-sum

I am trying to get a c program to ask me how many items i am buying than to ask the price for each item while keeping a rolling total and than ask again in a loop. I have the loop working fine but am having problems getting it to give me proper output.

here is the output i am getting when i run it.
http://i119.photobucket.com/albums/o134/halodude808/assignment2_zpsd46e84b8.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //variables used
    float penny = .01;
    float nickel = .05;
    float dime = .1;
    float quarter = .25;
    int items = 0;
    float paid= 0.0;
    float total = 0.0;
    float price =0.0;
    int counter =0.0;

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number of grocery items:");
        scanf("%d", &items);
        for (counter = 1; counter <= items; counter++)
        {
            printf("Please enter the price for item #%d:", counter);
            scanf("%f", &price);

            total += price;


        }
        printf("items = %d total = %f \n", &items, &total);
        getchar();
        getchar();

    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("items = %f total = %f \n", &items, &total);` should be `printf("items = %d total = %f \n", items, total);` - `items` is an `int`, not a `float`. And there's no need to pass the address of the variables, just their values.

Comment: fixed that but its giving me a 0 for total and a long string of numbers for items.

Comment: On my machine it's fine. Notice that you edited your question and fixed the `%f` specifier, but didn't remove the `&` operator from `items` and `total`.

Comment: 'float' variables should be initialized with '0.0f;   The current code is getting an int value '0', and converting it.

Comment: @jparks54: Did you change both the `%f` to `%d` and get rid of the `&` in the `printf` statement? In your edit, you only did the former.

Comment: the returned value from calls to scanf() (and family) should always be checked to assure all the input/conversion format specifiers were successful

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/PYHLtl) is a working version of your code.

Comment: got it after i fixed the & from items and total thanks Daniel if you put your comment as an answer i will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 printf("items = %f total = %f \n", &items, &total);
```

to

```
printf("items = %i total = %f \n", items, total);
```

Also, you might want to consider checking for invalid values (zeroes, negative, characters, etc).